# php file_get_contents sending wrong content-type to a Bugzilla install

Tags: php, file-get-contents, bugzilla

I am creating a script that should send a request to a bugzilla installation in order to login a user and post bugs.

I am using BugzillaPHP available on Google Code http://code.google.com/p/bugzillaphp/
all is working fine on my local server but not on a remote server where the script should run from.

The error I am getting back from Bugzilla is:

> Content-Type must be 'text/xml,' 'multipart/*,' 'application/soap+xml,' 'or 'application/dime' instead of 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded'

This means that my script is sending in the header a wrong content-type (or Bugzilla is incorrectly detecting the header). 
However I am pretty sure the content-type is set to the correct value.
This is my code:

```
    $context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-Type: text/html',
        'content' => $body
    )));


    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

What php version is your remote server?  There is a bug in 5.2 that blocks headers from being sent.  Need to add to ini_set before stream_context_create:

```
    $params = array('http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => 'Content-Type: text/html',
        'content' => $body
    ));

    // workaround for php bug where http headers don't get sent in php 5.2 
    if(version_compare(PHP_VERSION, '5.3.0') == -1){ 
        ini_set('user_agent', 'PHP-SOAP/' . PHP_VERSION . "\r\n" . $params['http']['header']); 
    } 

    $context = stream_context_create($params);
    $response = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Comment: No luck. The remote server is on PHP 5.3.3 - The local server where the script is working in PHP 5.3.6. Unfortunately the remote server is shared hosting, otherwise I would just copy the same settings over.

Answer (score 1):

You should store headers in array.

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array(
    'method' => 'POST',
    'header' => array("Content-Type: text/html"),
    'content' => $body
)));
```

Comment: I have just tried this now but I am getting the same result. Also this wouldn't explain why it's perfectly working on my local server. I've also tried with \r\n at the end of the content-type. Thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

```
$context = stream_context_create(array('http' => array(
        'method' => 'POST',
        'header' => "Content-Type: text/html\r\n",
        'content' => $body
    )));
```

Notice the `\r\n` at the end of the header value.

Comment: I have just tried this now but I am getting the same result. Also this wouldn't explain why it's perfectly working on my local server. Thanks anyway